# Doesn't see the SOAP header?

Tags: c#, asp.net, soap

i tried to make request to SOAP api.
I found similar question, but it didn't help.

Request example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="site:/schemas.xmlsoap/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Header>
      <Security xmlns="site:/docs.oasis-open/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsse="site:/docs.oasis-open/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="site:/docs.oasis-open/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:Username>ad</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="site/docs.oasis-open/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">V9ryhODmkSb+YH+RrugFn0Fe1Zc=</wsse:Password>
            <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="site:/docs.oasis-open/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">Uflrhc5221IfwxXTJrUgluSyksvq7nyFOfPMEbdY8UJ80kqoK1UxZfpFHfoTszg3oDCHpX+zmYZaJ/vuXrAm1g==</wsse:Nonce>
            <wsu:Created>2016-06-29T21:07:59Z</wsu:Created>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </Security>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body xmlns:xsd="site/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="site/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <getById xmlns="...">
         <id xmlns="">777</id>
      </getById>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Okay, i making model

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "UsernameToken")]
public class UsernameToken
{

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Username")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Password")]
    public Password Password { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Nonce")]
    public Nonce Nonce { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Created")]
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "wsse")]
    public string Wsse { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "wsu")]
    public string Wsu { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Security")]
public class Security
{

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "UsernameToken")]
    public UsernameToken UsernameToken { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xmlns")]
    public string Xmlns { get; set; }
 
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Header")]
public class Header
{

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Security")]
    public Security Security { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Password")]
public class Password
{

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Nonce")]
public class Nonce
{

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "EncodingType")]
    public string EncodingType { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class GetUpdatesRequest : getUpdates
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Header")]
    public Header Header { get; set; }
}
```

Making request and send

```
        var created = DateTimeOffset.Now;
        var nonce = GetNonce();
        var createdStr = created.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
        var password = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(GetSha1String(nonce + createdStr + _password));
        
        var req2 = new GetUpdatesRequest()
        {
            from = DateTime.Now,
            Header = new Header
            {
                Security = new Security
                {
                    Xmlns = "site:/docs.oasis-open/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd",
                    UsernameToken = new UsernameToken
                    {
                        Created = created,
                        Nonce = new Nonce
                        {
                            EncodingType = "site:/docs.oasis-open/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary",
                            Text = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(nonce))
                        },
                        Password = new Password
                        {
                            Text = Convert.ToBase64String(password),
                            Type = "site:/docs.oasis-open/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest"
                        },
                        Username = _username,
                        Wsse = "site:/docs.oasis-open/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd",
                        Wsu = "site:/docs.oasis-open/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        
        var result = await _service.getUpdatesAsync(req2).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return result;
    }

    private static string GetNonce()
    {
        return Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }

    private string GetSha1String(string phrase)
    {
        var sha1Hasher = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
        var hashedDataBytes = sha1Hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(phrase));
        return Convert.ToBase64String(hashedDataBytes);
    }
```

And i'm receive exception

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException: An error was discovered processing the <wsse:Security> header
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.TaskCreator.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<CreateGenericTask>b__0(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
```

what is the problem? What i'm doing is wrong?

I tried to make some change in model, but it useless.
Tried to change wsHttpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType set to Digest.
Soap UI is execute successful this request